# Чтение базы данных из файла и запись в массив

Tags: c++, потоки-данных

Здравствуйте, подскажите, как можно прочитать базу данных, хранящуюся в .txt файле и имеющую подобный формат:

Val  1   0  1.209279

Файл содержит около 1500 строк и 4 столбца (название величины, координата X, координата Y и значение), каким образом можно считать последний столбец и записать его в массив?

Comment: ну элементарно прочитать каждую строку целиком и разбить по пробелу...

Comment: а зачем читать всю "базу данных"?? с точки зрения использования ресурсов не рационально, можно сделать буфер с нужными полями конечной длины и с определнной позиции вычитывать нужный размер данных. тогда скорость работы будет выше.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
//Линия в файле. Стоит дать полям боле осмысленные имена, но для примера сойдет
struct Line{
    std::string first;
    int second;
    int third;
    double fourth;
};
//Оператор чтения линии из файла
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Line &line){
    is >> line.first;
    is >> line.second;
    is >> line.third;
    is >> line.fourth;
    return is;
}
//Функциональный объект, для того чтобы можно было вынуть из Line последнее значние
struct LineFourth{
    inline double operator()(const Line &line) const{
        return line.fourth;
    }
};

int main(int, char*)
{
    std::vector<double> values;
    std::ifstream file("data.txt", std::ifstream::in);
    if(!file){
        //Не удалось открыть файл
        return 1;
    }

    std::istream_iterator<Line> begin(file);
    std::istream_iterator<Line> end;

    //Чтение файла построчно. В values будет помещен последний столбец
    std::transform(begin, end, std::back_inserter(values), LineFourth());

    //Дальше можно что-то делать с values
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: но можно проще,засунуть структуру в вектор и не париться с функциями  для вытаскивания.

Comment: @Akuma925, ну да, так даже проще `std::copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter(values);` Но ведь человек хотел именно последний столбец в виде массива.

Comment: ну дак ничго не мешает потом из вектора повытаскивать все значения этого поля и заталкать их в массив это один цикл

Comment: @Akuma925, не вижу смысла делать задачу в два действия, если можно в одно. Вот если ему другие поля потом понадобятся, тогда дело другое.

Answer (score 0):

Перебираешь строчки... Прочитал строку, нашёл пробел - это 1-ое значение, следущий пробел - 2-ое значение и т.д. до конца строки